# In the Deryni novels of Katherine Kurtz, how to resolve the Valoret sacristy portal discrepancy?

Tags: deryni-series

In *The Harrowing of Gwynedd*, Kai Descantor dies destroying the portal in the sacristy of the Valoret cathedral.  Javan later confirms that it was indeed destroyed.

In *The Quest for Saint Camber*, Arilan and Duncan use the portal in the sacristy of the Valoret cathedral to transfer to Rhemuth. (I believe the sacristy portal is also functional when an attempt is made to attack Brion shortly before his crowning, in one of the books of the Childe Morgan trilogy, when Rhydon got the scar on his face...).

Kai Descantor destroyed the portal.  There are no Deryni in the church hierarchy for the next, I believe, 200 years.  How and why is the portal functioning in King Brion and King Kelson's time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Via [The Worlds of Katherine Kurtz](https://www.rhemuthcastle.com/index.php), I got an answer from the author.

Her response to the question was, " That's a Gotcha, --though I suppose it could have been reinstated in the intervening years."

Further discussion between her and a few fans concluded that probably it was reinstated in 948 or around the time of the Battle of Killingford, about which a novel has not yet been written.

You can see the discussion, including the report of the discussion with the author, [here](https://www.rhemuthcastle.com/index.php/topic,2602.0.html).